# Look for better performance on arpy geodatabase

Tags: esri, arcpy

I need to export 50+- feature classes from ArcSDE to a file GDB regularly. GDB is for read-only. Which way it performs best?

- Drop the old GDB and recreate one, then reload all feature classes?
- Keep the old GDB and drop all feature classes,  then re-create them and load data?
- Keep the old GDB and all feature classes, then truncate the old data and re-load the new data?

Thank you.